# Type Passing / Changing

Tags: java, tree, tree-nodes

```
public abstract class ASTNode3 extends ASTNode {

    ASTNode child1;
    ASTNode child2;
    ASTNode child3;

    public ASTNode3(ASTNode c1, ASTNode c2, ASTNode c3) {
    child1 = c1;
    child2 = c2;
    child3 = c3;
    }

    public ASTNode getChild1() {
    return child1;
    }

    public ASTNode getChild2() {
    return child2;
    }

    public ASTNode getChild3() {
    return child3;
    }
}

public class IRProc extends ASTNode3 {

    public IRProc (String p, Vector v, IRCmdSeq cmds) {
    super(p,v,cmds);
    }
```

I extended the ASTNode as shown below, but when i try to pass in a Vector and a String as arguments I keep getting errors. How can I pass in these values without affecting the node. I was thinking of creating an intermediate class that handle the type, but i don't know how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line

```
super(p,v,cmds);
```

you try to call the constructor `ASTNode3(ASTNode c1, ASTNode c2, ASTNode c3)` with the arguments `String p, Vector v, IRCmdSeq cmds`. This doesn't match.

You have to create instances of `ASTNode` to call `super()`. How you do this depends on what you want to do. Perhaps you should explain what kind of information `p`, `v` and `cmds` actually contain.

Comment: p is a String identifier, v is a Vector of parameters while cmd is some commands. i'm trying to build a compiler